# append .xml to EE template

Tags: url, htaccess, routing, rss

Client has a podcast feed that up until now has been a manually edited XML file on their server.

I'm looking to move this into EE so that they don't need to touch the server directly.

Because this was a manual XML edit, the file was at /media/podcast.xml

Converting to EE /media/podcast works just grand, however, for those still looking at /media/podcast.xml - they get a 404.

What's the best way to route those users to the /media/podcast url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best is a redirect on the server. It's faster and easier.

If the server runs Apache, you can add to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/media/podcast.xml http://domain.com/media/podcast [L,R=302]
```

If everything goes right, replace the `302` by `301`.